# Why Ctrl+\ does nothing in BASH terminal?

Tags: linux, bash

I am running Ubuntu on Windows. I see Ctrl+\ should generate Linux signal SIGQUIT which it should terminate the process and also generate a core file. I tried it at the BASH terminal, but it did nothing, whereare Ctrl-D immediatelly closed the BASH terminal.

Could you elaborate why Ctrl-\ has no effect?

```
$ stty -a | grep quit
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate on Unix & Linux: [Does SIGQUIT not have the effect of terminating a script in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/555295/117037) TL;DR "Bash ignores `SIGQUIT`"

Comment: I assume that in your running bash it is not defined what should happen when the signal SIGQUIT is received. Take a look at `trap -p SIGQUIT` (no output) and try this: `trap 'echo "SIGQUIT received"' SIGQUIT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely Bash ignores SIGQUIT. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555295/does-sigquit-not-have-the-effect-of-terminating-a-script-in-bash) is a Stack Exchange Post that explains it well. This should explains it.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the bullet point therein about questions that "are not about programming as defined in the help center". The appropriate way to guide people asking off-topic questions towards the place they'll get their question answered is with a comment, not an answer; thus, there was no reason to duplicate the information wjandrea had already provided.